# Passing a argument with '!' with bash

Tags: php, bash

I want to pass a string to a php script which contains `!` character. Like this

```
php cfg.php --name=smtppass --set="MYW!ORD"
```

But I get this error

```
bash: !ORD: event not found
```

On the other hand, if I pass `"MYW\!ORD"`, I see this string is set when I query the file

```
smtppass        MYW\!ORD
```

Any idea to fix that?

Comment: `set +H` to disable history expanion

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it like this:

```sh
php cfg.php --name=smtppass --set="MYW"'!'"ORD"
```

or a more lazy way would be to use single quotes.

```sh
php cfg.php --name=smtppass --set='MYW!ORD'
```

This happens because of Bash's history expansion, which is sometimes very dangerous, you could turn this feature off by typing `set +H`.